# Is there a word or phrase for drinking from a cup which is full without lifting it?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Someone has a cup that is full and when lifted, the content of the cup will get spilled.

Is there a specific word or a phrase that can describe the act of kneeling or bending down and sipping from the cup without lifting it from the table until it becomes possible to lift the cup without spilling?

Comment: "Slurp' (or even 'lap', but that's difficult) comes to mind.

Comment: I reckon *skimming* would fit here, although it doesn't cover "without lifting the container".

Comment: How about *suck*?

Comment: @NagarajanShanmuganathan: that word covers the drinking part, but doesn't imply anything about the lifting or lack of lifting of the cup that is done while drinking. My first choice for a 'drinking' verb would probably be 'sip', since that implies drinking small amounts at a time, which might imply more care while drinking.

Comment: *Bringing his mouth down to the brimming cup, he took a few sips of the tea*.

Comment: @MarkRipley  I'd opt for *slurp* over *sip*: to me a 'sip' involves taking up liquid with no air, you form a seal between your lips, the cup wall and surface of the liquid and suck gently. The contact with the liquid risks displacement of liquid out of the cup if you don't judge it right, and leaning down to a cup makes the angle of approach tricky. *Slurping* otoh doesn't require a seal, only a sufficiently vigorous sucking action, deployed, as you approach the drink, for some liquid to be wrenched upwards to your mouth with the in-rushing air. TL:DR Sipping's quiet, slurping's noisy

Comment: You should use a straw.

Comment: This is something that is only rarely done, so there is no set phrase that would be recognized by most readers.

Comment: @HotLicks You clearly don't belong to that rather large section of the population who drink their tea/coffee with milk and are incorrigibly incapable of judging the right amount to pour in before the milk. There are quite a lot of people who do the exact thing this question asks about on a daily basis.

Comment: Whichever verb you end up going with, maybe you could add “at” to it to imply that it’s something different/more/less/  than  just your normal sip or slurp (both of which, imo, can be done with cup in hand) (adding “cautiously/preemptively” and @WS2 ‘s “brimming” would also help a lot!): … She [cautiously/preemptively] slurped/sipped/sucked/bobbed/kissed?/puckered? **at** the [brimming] cup [before raising it to her lips for that first real delicious sip].

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Of course if you had been born to the working class, as I was, you would know that the milk goes in before the tea. The reason for this is that the poor quality China cups used by those 'beneath the salt' were not strong enough to take boiling liquid. Hence the cold milk was put in first to avoid the possibility of the cup cracking. (tea is always made with boiling water, unlike coffee).

Comment: @WS2 It's not so much that I wasn't born to the working class, but that I was born too late. We never drank tea and coffee from china cups, but from ceramic mugs—china cups were generally considered quite posh, much posher than we ever were, when I was a child, though they're making a comeback this millennium. Plus tea wasn't made with boiling water half the time either, but that's just ’cause we're uncultivated plebs. :-p

Answer (score 2):

I end up having to do this quite often and when I do I ***slurp***.  It may not be attractive or polite, but slurping is what the circumstance calls for especially for hot drinks, even if straws are available.  Slurping not only allows spill-free drinking, it also cools a too-hot drink (unlike a straw).

***Slurp*** - To make a sucking noise in drinking or eating (OED).

Answer (score 0):

When you are ***bobbing for apples***, you are playing a game to retrieve apples from a tub of water using only your mouth without using your arms or hands. So you could metaphorically apply this to your situation:

> As the cup was overfull, he ***bobbed for water*** until he could pick it up.

Comment: Is someone contending *bobbing for apples* is not a recognized term for trying to get an apple out of a tub into their mouth without using their hands?

Comment: I can't speak for "someone," but I think it's not a very good metaphor. When I imagine someone bobbing for apples, I picture that person's while face getting submerged. When someone drinks water from the top of a cup, they just use their lips.

Comment: @suməlic: The easiest apple to get is the one on top of the other apples, no need to get wet. You only get wet if you have to go for a submerged apple. Analogous to bobbing for more water even though the cup is only half full.

Answer (score 0):

The closest phrase I can think of is **'slurping in situ'**, where **'slurping'** indicates drinking by using your lips to noisily inhale the liquid, and **'in situ'** indicates not moving the cup in order to drink from it.